# (SECURITY) npm audit with gitlab CI

Tags: npm, gitlab, continuous-integration

How can I stop a build if the `package.json` contains a critical security flaw by doing `npm audit` in `gitlab-ci.yml`?

Answer (score 3):

Create a job in your pipeline which runs ...

```
npm audit --audit-level=critical
```

Any critical vulnerabilities will cause it to exit with a non-zero exit code, which should then cause the job to fail and block further progress.